EV of Martingale with finite bankroll, stopping after 1 win
Suppose we are playing a betting game with probability p of winning with a fixed starting bankroll of n coins. If we win, then we double our bet, if we lose, then we lose all of the money we put in. Consider a strategy where we start off by betting 1 coin. If we lose, then we bet 2 coins, if we lose again then we bet 4 coins, and so on until we finally win a toss. What is the expected profit?

As you say, for a fair coin, the expected value of the profit is exactly 0. This is a consequence of (or rather, the statement) of the optional stopping theorem

If the odds is 50-50, then the EV of this strategy is zero. This is because with martingale, after a loss, you only win 1 coin.
